# Can't seem to be able to pass data from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-service

The issue is that I can't seem to send information from Controller 1 to Controller 2... I have my service that sets/gets data but it isn't working. The actual error that I'm getting is that Controller 1's dataService.getData is not a function... when it works elsewhere.

Service 1 (in its own file)

```
app.service('dataService', function() {
    var data, queried;
    return {
        setData: function(queryData) {
            this.data = queryData;
            this.queried = false;
        },
        getData: function() {
            this.queried = true;
            return this.data;
        }
    }; 
});
```

Controller 1 (sending information)

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', function($scope, $location, $state, dataService) {
    anotherService.functionName(function(err, data) {
        // do some things here
        actualService.doesntWork(function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                var query = {};
                query.someField = data.someField;
                dataService.setData(query);
                $state.go("go.somewhere.else");
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

Controller 2 (getting information)

```
app.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', function($scope, $location, $state, dataService) {
    $scope.buttonPressed = function() {
        console.log(dataService.getData());
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't injected service `dataService` inside your `MyCtrl` & `MyCtrl2`, ensure dependency should be injected before using it.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state','dataService', //<-added dependency here
   function($scope, $location, $state, dataService) {
    anotherService.functionName(function(err, data) {
        // do some things here
        actualService.doesntWork(function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                var query = {};
                query.someField = data.someField;
                dataService.setData(query);
                $state.go("go.somewhere.else");
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

**Controller2**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$location', '$state','dataService',//<-added dependency here 
  function($scope, $location, $state, dataService) {
    $scope.buttonPressed = function() {
        console.log(dataService.getData());
    }
}]);
```

Comment: a much easier and more maintainable solution it to not define the injectables in the array, remove the array entirely and just use the function. `.controller('MyCtrl2', function($scope, $location, $state, dataService) {})`

Comment: @Enzey no that is not good solution, as per angular doc if you don't follow the `strict-di` then it will break js while doing minification, you need to read this http://toddmotto.com/angular-js-dependency-injection-annotation-process/

Comment: Yes, following strict-di is needed for minification however there are tools such as `grunt-ng-annotate` will apply the strict-di fo you. Thus freeing you from needing to follow this annoying and ugly pattern just to be able to minify the code.

Comment: @Enzey its not ugly pattern..I follow this pattern in `.Net` code, actually I don't know how to use grunt with .Net, If you know please share that link